# My code inside `$.when` block is not firing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use `$.when(some function).then(some function)` in jQuery to force a callback function to wait until the code in `$.when()` finishes first.

Here is my function.

```
function activateFirstTab(callback) {

    console.log('started activateFirstTab');
    console.log('Total groups found: '+ $('.functionParameterGroup').length);

    $.when(function () {

        $('.functionParameterGroup').each(function () {
            //Activate the first tab "which is the default"

            var first = $(this).find('ul > li:first');

            first.addClass('active');

            var contentId = first.data('contentid');

            $(contentId).addClass('in active');

            console.log('finished when logic in activateFirstTab');

        });

    }).then(function () {

        // Make sure the callback is a function​
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            // Call it, since we have confirmed it is callable​
            callback();
        }

    });


    console.log('finished activateFirstTab');

}
```

In the console I get the following messages

```
started activateFirstTab
Total groups found: 2
finished activateFirstTab
```

but I never get the message from the block inside `$.when()`

I am expecting the output to be this

```
started activateFirstTab
Total groups found: 2
finished when logic in activateFirstTab
finished when logic in activateFirstTab
finished activateFirstTab
```

Why the code inside `$.when()` is not being executed?

How can I make it execute it? what mistake am I making?

Comment: Shouldn't `$.when` be called on a deferred object? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/

Comment: First of all your code is synchronous and doesn't need all of this.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko are you saying if I get rid of `$.when().then()` my code will anyway wait until it is done before it calls the callback?

Comment: @Jaylen Yes, it doesn't have anything async in it.  DOM lookups and mutations are sync.

Comment: @noahnu `$.when()` can accept any type of parameter

Comment: @YuryTarabanko although you did not answer my question directly, you actually tough me something and helped me fix the problem that I created unintentionally due to misunderstanding. If you post an answer and I will vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not call the function within `$.when()`, also note the anonymous function passed to `$.when()` does not return a promise; though any type of parameter can be passed to `$.when()`

```js
function fn(callback) {
  $.when(function dfd(callback) {
      $.each([1, 2, 3], function(i, value) {
        console.log(value)
      });
      return "dfd complete"
    }() /* invoke `dfd` function */ )
    .then(function(data) {
      // Make sure the callback is a function​
      if (typeof callback === "function") {
        // Call it, since we have confirmed it is callable​
        callback(data);
      }
    })
}

fn(function(args) {
  alert(args)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Moreover, he does not have a Promise-compatible object inside `$.when()`

Comment: not sure that I understand. my foreach method is inside the $.when(). are you saying $.when will not call my function?

Comment: @Jaylen Yes, `$.when()` does not call function

Comment: @Aaron `$.when()` can accept any parameter. Though, yes, you are correct